# Custom annotation to get custom object with specified set of @RequestHeaders from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking for the way to create custom annotation to read set of headers from `HttpServletRequest`

Let's say I have a following code:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/path")
    public void method(@RequestHeader("session-session_id") long sessionId,
                       @RequestHeader("session-user_id") long userId,
                       @RequestHeader("session-user_name") String userName) {
        UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.of(sessionId, userId, userName);
        //service.handle(userInfo);
    }

    public static final class UserInfo {
        private final long sessionId;
        private final long userId;
        private final String userName;

        private UserInfo(long sessionId, long userId, String userName) {
            this.sessionId = sessionId;
            this.userId = userId;
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public static UserInfo of(long sessionId, long userId, String userName) {
            return new UserInfo(sessionId, userId, userName);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have user info in request headers. All user info headers will start with "session-" prefix. On the real system I will have more than 3 fields. And they will be used for a lot of requests.
So, I have to transfer to service level an object with full user info. And creation of this `UserInfo` for each request like `UserInfo.of(sessionId, userId, userName)` looks redundant and pretty ugly. Thats is the problem.

I know at least 2 another ways to solve this:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/path")
public void method(HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.of(request);
}

public static UserInfo of(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //request.getHeader("header name");
}
```

or

```
@PostMapping(path = "/path")
public void method(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> request) {
    UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.of(request);
}

public static UserInfo of(Map<String, String> request) {
    //map.get("header name");
}
```

But still it isn't the case. I'm looking for the way to create `UserInfo` like spring does it:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/path")
public void method(@UserInfo UserInfo request) {
    UserInfo userInfo = UserInfo.of(request);
}
```

Could you help me with a solution? Or at least provide a link to documentation where described how `@RequestHeader` implemented inside the spring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define custom [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html):

```
public class UserInfoResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        return parameter.getParameterType().equals(UserInfo.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter parameter,
                                  ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest,
                                  WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        // There are no null-checks here for simplicity, 
        // so don't forget to add them in production code
        return UserInfo(
            Long.parseLong(webRequest.getHeader("session-session_id")), 
            Long.parseLong(webRequest.getHeader("session-user_id")),
            webRequest.getHeader("session-user_name")
        );
    }
}
```

Then make Spring aware of that argument resolver in your web configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebApiConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    ...

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new UserInfoResolver());
    }

    ...
}
```

And finally you can use it this way:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/path")
public void method(UserInfo userInfo) {
    //service.handle(userInfo);
}
```

Comment: how to do this with annotations? something more of aspect oriented programming?